# C++ MACROS: conditional code include in expression NOT statement

Tags: c++, macros, boost-preprocessor, x-macros

Ok I know macros are evil and should be avoided at all costs.  I am trying to reduce significant boiler plate code and repetition that will be difficult to not commit typo mistakes if I can't macrotize it.

This is a somewhat contrived example as I tried to reduce the real code I have to a more concise example.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison/equal.hpp>

using FUNC = std::function<int(int,int)>;

#define BINDIF( method ) BOOST_PP_IF(1,std::bind(&B::method, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),nullptr)
//                                   ^ this needs to vary on value of the method param
//                                   ^ I tried BOOST_PP_EQUAL(nullptr, method) here
//                                     it concatenated several Boost macros and threw
//                                     an error about not recognizing the long symbol
//                                     it created

#define TABLE       \
T(Add, add)         \
T(Sub, sub)         \
T(Mul, mul)         \
T(Div, div)

#define T(k,v) k,
enum Ops: size_t {
    TABLE
};
#undef T

class A {
public:
    FUNC Func;
    A(FUNC func)
        : Func(func) {
    }
};

class B {
    std::map<Ops,A> As;
public:
    int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
    int sub(int x, int y) { return x - y; }
    int mul(int x, int y) { return x * y; }
    int div(int x, int y) { return x / y; }

    B() {

        #define T(k,v) std::make_pair(Ops::k, A( BINDIF(v) ) ),
        As = {
            TABLE
        };
        #undef T
    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This will correctly expand the std::bind code found in the BINDIF macro.  However, notice that the first parameter, the conditional, is set to 1.  If I change this value to 0, it correctly drops in the value, nullptr.  The problem is that I would like this happen when evaluating the 'method' param passed to the BINDIF macro.  I would like to have nullptr values entered in the table and therefore the std::bind code won't be generated.

I am fully aware how contrived this example seems, but with the actual code I am working with most columns have nullptr in them as I sparsely bind to one of 4 std::function pointers.

Here is the expansion with 1:

```
><(((º> g++ -E -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp

...removed for brevity

class B {
    std::map<Ops,A> As;
public:
    int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
    int sub(int x, int y) { return x - y; }
    int mul(int x, int y) { return x * y; }
    int div(int x, int y) { return x / y; }

    B() {


        As = {
            std::make_pair(Ops::Add, A( std::bind(&B::add, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2) ) ), 
            std::make_pair(Ops::Sub, A( std::bind(&B::sub, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2) ) ), 
            std::make_pair(Ops::Mul, A( std::bind(&B::mul, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2) ) ), 
            std::make_pair(Ops::Div, A( std::bind(&B::div, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2) ) ),
        };

    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the expansion with 0:

```
><(((º> g++ -E -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp

...removed for brevity

class B {
    std::map<Ops,A> As;
public:
    int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
    int sub(int x, int y) { return x - y; }
    int mul(int x, int y) { return x * y; }
    int div(int x, int y) { return x / y; }

    B() {


        As = {
            std::make_pair(Ops::Add, A( nullptr ) ), 
            std::make_pair(Ops::Sub, A( nullptr ) ), 
            std::make_pair(Ops::Mul, A( nullptr ) ), 
            std::make_pair(Ops::Div, A( nullptr ) ),
        };

    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Please excuse any typos and the overall length of this question.  I searched the last several days for an answer here and elsewhere and couldn't find anything that seemed to work.  Boost's macro documentation is pretty sparse.

Lol, sure.  The table with a nullptr like this:

```
#define TABLE       \
T(Add, add)         \
T(Sub, sub)         \
T(Mul, mul)         \
T(Div, nullptr)
```

Would result in code like this:

```
As = {
    std::make_pair(Ops::Add, A( std::bind(&B::add, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2) ) ), 
    std::make_pair(Ops::Sub, A( std::bind(&B::sub, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2) ) ), 
    std::make_pair(Ops::Mul, A( std::bind(&B::mul, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2) ) ),
    std::make_pair(Ops::Div, A( nullptr ) ),
};
```

Comment: For the sake of someone with no attention span, could you perhaps add a very simple, short, pseudo-example of what final syntax you would like and what it should do?

Comment: I added an addendum showing how the table would affect the resulting code...

Comment: I tried using BOOST_PP_EQUAL(nullptr, method) in place of the 0 or 1, but it concatenates a bunch of Boost macros and then says they don't exist.

Comment: If `Add`, `Sub`, etc. do not have to be member functions you can avoid implementing them yourself by using `std::plus`, `std::minus`, etc. If they do need to be member functions at least declare them `const`. You can probably take advantage of initializer lists and replace the assignment with something like `As = std::map<Ops, A>{ { Op1, A() }, { Op2, A() } };`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious yeah this is not the real example, just something simple readers would be able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this problem is unsolvable via MACROS.  I think it is going to require template meta-programming power at this point.  For anyone interested I need at *compile time* to either passthru nullptr, or bind to a class method.  The search continues...